# PAYPAL Pro - Currency not supported Error

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal Pro for my transaction within webiste , but the currency I would like to use is Canadian Dollar , so I removed USD and added CAD but the processing was not working I also tried CAN even it shows error. Anyone can help me please. The error sometimes shown is CURRENCY NOT SUPPORTED  or else INVALID CREDIT CARD TYPE/NUMBER.I am using PHP language for the website and even created live API credentilas for the same.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Those two errors are completely different, and each are pretty straight forward, telling you exactly what your problem is.

The correct currency code for Canadian Dollar is CAD, so use that and that will eliminate your Currency Not Supported error (unless your PayPal account happens to be setup to not support a particular currency.)

Then for the invalid credit card type / number you just need to double check the values that you're passing in because one of them must be incorrect.  If you want to post a sample of your API request here I can help you with that.